# SoftEtherのVPNサーバに同じLAN内の複数のクライアントから同時接続する方法

Tags: network

SoftEterのVPNをサーバを立て、
外部のネットワークからVPNサーバにアクセスすることを考えています。

無事、MacやiPhoneなどでVPNサーバに接続することができたのですが、
同じLAN内にある２つの端末から同時に同じVPNサーバにアクセスしようとすると、
初めの端末はアクセスできますが、二つ目の端末はアクセスできない状態です。

そこで二つ目の端末を別のネットワーク(携帯のテザリングなど)から
同じVPNサーバにアクセスすると、
その場合はちゃんとVPNアクセスできました。

おそらく同じLANに端末は、VPNサーバ側からみると同じIPに見えるので
初めの端末は許可されますが、二台目の端末は拒否されたのかなと想像しています。

このように同じLAN内から、
外部ネットワーク上のSoftEther VPNサーバに
同時に複数台の端末でアクセスしたい時は、
どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？

この問題の対処の方法を知っている方がいらっしゃったら、教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: VPNサーバのログを見ることはできますか? まずはログを見ることで、「想像しています」の想像を確信に変えていけるかと思います。

Comment: @masm さん。コメントありがとうございます。SoftEtherの公式フォーラムで、原因と思われる事柄を教えて頂いたので、追記させて頂きました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決したので、自分で回答させて頂きます。

上記の問題の原因は、自分の家のルータがVPNパススルーに対応していないため、
同じLANからは複数台接続できないとのことでした。

[SoftEther VPN User Forum • View topic - VPNサーバに同じLANから複数同時接続できない件](http://www.vpnusers.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=7953)

VPNパススルーに対応したルータを購入すれば、解決するかと思います。